# How do I sum values ​in one place with the same ID number in different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

for example I have 3 tables,

First Table

```
|PrjID|ProjectType|
 1     Sample
```

Second Table

```
|PrjID|ProjectEng|
 1     Joe Doen
```

Third Table

```
|PrjID|ProjectDate|
 1     20112020
```

I want to sum values ​​in one table with the same ID number in different tables like this :

```
|PrjID|ProjectType|ProjectEng|ProjectDate|
1      Sample      Joe Doen   20112020
```

I have about 150 data tables. How can I sum values ​​in one table with the same ID number in different tables with query?

Comment: Sum what values?  What results do you want?

Comment: Seems odd that you would store all this data in separate tables. To ask a silly question, but you are aware a table can have more than 2 columns, right? All this data should be in a single table.

Comment: @Larnu When I took a break and thought logically, I thought to myself what am I doing. I was working for a long time without taking a break. My brain melted hahahahahha LOL

Comment: I fixed the table now it works as it should

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are having another fourth table containing PrjID and containing values in the val column and you want to sum val column.

```sql
SELECT f.PrjID, s.ProjectEng, t.ProjectDate, SUM(f.val) --Assuming you want to sum val column
FROM FirstTable as f
INNER JOIN SecondTable as s
ON s.PrjID = f.PrjID
Inner Join ThirdTable as t
ON t.PrjID = f.PrjID
Inner Join FourthTable as fo --Assuming this table has value column
ON fo.PrjID = f.PrjID
GROUP BY f.PrjID, s.ProjectEng, t.ProjectDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `join`?

```
select t1.*, t1.projecttype, t2.projecteng, t3.projectdate
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.prjid =  t2.prjid join
     t3
     on t1.projid = t3.projid;
```